Plugin [id: 'com.android.application', version: '8.7.2', apply: false] was not found in any of the following sources:
Here’s a properly formatted version of your question for Stack Overflow. It ensures clarity and proper code formatting to avoid the error about unformatted code.

Title: Gradle Plugin Not Found: 'com.android.application' version '8.7.2'
I encountered an error while trying to create a new Android project with Gradle. Here’s the error message I’m getting:
     Error: Build file 'A:\Android\Advertising\build.gradle.kts' line: 2

     Plugin [id: 'com.android.application', version: '8.7.2', apply: false] was not                  found in any of the following sources:

* Try:
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
> Get more help at https://help.gradle.org.

* Exception is:
org.gradle.api.plugins.UnknownPluginException: Plugin [id: 'com.android.application', version: '8.7.2', apply: false] was not found in any of the following sources:

- Gradle Core Plugins (plugin is not in 'org.gradle' namespace)
- Included Builds (No included builds contain this plugin)
- Plugin Repositories (could not resolve plugin artifact 'com.android.application:com.android.application.gradle.plugin:8.7.2')
  Searched in the following repositories:
    Google
    MavenRepo

build.gradle.kts
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
plugins {
    alias(libs.plugins.android.application) apply false
    alias(libs.plugins.kotlin.android) apply false
}

libs.version.toml
[versions]
agp = "8.7.2"
kotlin = "1.9.24"
coreKtx = "1.15.0"
junit = "4.13.2"
junitVersion = "1.2.1"
espressoCore = "3.6.1"
appcompat = "1.7.0"
material = "1.12.0"
activity = "1.9.3"
constraintlayout = "2.2.0"

[libraries]
androidx-core-ktx = { group = "androidx.core", name = "core-ktx", version.ref = "coreKtx" }
junit = { group = "junit", name = "junit", version.ref = "junit" }
androidx-junit = { group = "androidx.test.ext", name = "junit", version.ref = "junitVersion" }
androidx-espresso-core = { group = "androidx.test.espresso", name = "espresso-core", version.ref = "espressoCore" }
androidx-appcompat = { group = "androidx.appcompat", name = "appcompat", version.ref = "appcompat" }
material = { group = "com.google.android.material", name = "material", version.ref = "material" }
androidx-activity = { group = "androidx.activity", name = "activity", version.ref = "activity" }
androidx-constraintlayout = { group = "androidx.constraintlayout", name = "constraintlayout", version.ref = "constraintlayout" }

[plugins]
android-application = { id = "com.android.application", version.ref = "agp" }
kotlin-android = { id = "org.jetbrains.kotlin.android", version.ref = "kotlin" }

Problem:
When I try to create a new project, I get the above error stating that the plugin com.android.application version 8.7.2 cannot be found. I have verified my configuration but can't figure out the issue.
What I've Tried:

Ensured that the Google and MavenCentral repositories are included in my project.
Double-checked the version numbers in libs.versions.toml.
Searched online but couldn’t find version 8.7.2 in the official Android Gradle Plugin release notes.

Question:
Is version 8.7.2 of the Android Gradle Plugin officially released? If not, how should I resolve this issue? Should I downgrade to a stable version? If yes, which version is recommended?

Looks like a network issue. Can you access it directly? Here is the page at the repo listing for reference
